# What's the best way to move a data entry field in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I was wondering what was the best way to move an existing field from lets say a tab to another tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do so using only the layout editor and 6 simple steps.

1. Launch the Layout Editor for the Screen that contain the field that you want to move.
2. Select the field that you want to move. Make sure that all the options are being shown in the screen using the "Hide Advance property. Take note of every property that has something written in the value column.
3. Delete the field using the delete button at the top of the tree view.
4. In the tree view go the the field that is just above the new place where you want to have the field you just deleted. Go to the Add Data field tab and find the field that you have just deleted, check the checkbox and click the Create Controls button.
5. In the newly created field, go to the properties tab and put back all the values that you had seen on the original field before deleting it at the fourth step.
6. Publish the customization project.

Comment: One can also export the project and check the 'xml' file to make sure all field attributes were copied.